# woocommerce sort by dropdown styling

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

Right now "sort by price:low to high" background color is blue i want to change into pink.
The  website is in wordpress with woocommerce.

Comment: You may overwrite a css to its respected class. Do chrome inspect for getting it's particular class name so that it will give you a clear idea.

Comment: I already trying ..I can't do it.

Comment: You need to overwrite it with important parameter of css.